# Read a fastparquet file using Akka parquet

Tags: scala, akka, parquet, akka-stream, parquet-mr

I have one of our Python systems generating Parquet files using Pandas and fastparquet. These are to be read by a Scala system that runs atop Akka streams.

Akka does provide [a source for reading Avro Parquet files](https://doc.akka.io/docs/alpakka/current/avroparquet.html). However, when I try to read the file, I end up with

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: INT96 not yet implemented.
```

This is one of the columns that does not need to be read for the Scala application to work. My question is whether I can specify a schema and get just that one column out considering that the generated file is from fastparquet.

The relevant snippet which generates a source for reading Parquet files is:

```
.map(result => {
      val path = s"s3a://${result.bucketName}/${result.key}"
      val file = HadoopInputFile.fromPath(new Path(path), hadoopConfig)
      val reader: ParquetReader[GenericRecord] =
        AvroParquetReader
          .builder[GenericRecord](file)
          .withConf(hadoopConfig)
          .build()
      AvroParquetSource(reader)
    })
```